# how to execute dusk testing with parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-dusk, laravel-dusk2

i want execute laravel dusk test with parameter, so i did try like this

```
php artisan dusk --filter ExampleTest::testBasicExample( here parameter );
```

in the console, but it is not working and i got syntax error

i want to know what to execute testing code with parameter

it is impossible??

please tell me what to do .......

------ below is my dusk code

```
namespace Tests\Browser;

use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

class ExampleTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic browser test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample($aa = 'dd')
    {
        return dd($aa);
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit('https://www.naver.com');
            $aa = $browser->element('#account > div > div > span > a:nth-child(1)')->getAttribute('innerHTML');
        });
    }
```

Comment: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('      <<<<<< this is my console got

Comment: Your function's bracket is not closed. Missing a `}`

Comment: i see error like this 'bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('  in my console
but i have execute ' php artisan dusk --filter ExampleTest::testBasicExample( here parameter ); '  it is Wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't close the function `testBasicExample`. Add a curly bracket `}` after the `$this->browse(...)` line